# ConsoleKit reports active/is-local only on the second+ login

Tags: linux, pam

Running KDE Frameworks 5, Plasma 5, using `sddm` as a display manager.

`ConsoleKit` and `PAM-linux` are both installed.

Upon login (using the `sddm` login screen), `ck-list-sessions` returns `FALSE` for both `is-local` and `active`. Only one session is present.

If I log out, then back in, the two fields are both `TRUE`, as expected.

`sddm` is not a console-kit supporting dm. Therefore, I am using the `pam_ck_connector.so` module to attach a consolekit session.

The sddm startup file (`/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsession`) is modified to launch using the line:

```
eval exec "ck-launch-session dbus-lauch --exit-with-session $session"
```

The (I think relevant) pam files are as follows:

`/etc/pam.d/sddm`:

```
auth            include         system-auth
account         include         system-account
password        include         system-password
session         include         system-session
session         optional        pam_loginuid.so
session         optional        pam_ck_connector.so nox11
session         optional        pam_warn.so
```

`/etc/pam.d/sddm-greeter`:

```
# Load environment from /etc/environment and ~/.pam_environment
auth            required pam_env.so

# Always let the greeter start without authentication
auth            required pam_permit.so

# No action required for account management
account         required pam_permit.so

# Can't change password
password        required pam_deny.so

# Setup session
session         required pam_unix.so
#session        optional pam_loginuid.so
session         optional pam_ck_connector.so
session         optional pam_warn.so
```

`pam_warn.so` lines have been added to force logging to the `/var/log/auth.log` file. A typical login looks something like:

```
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm by (uid=0)
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_warn(sddm-greeter:session): function=[pam_sm_open_session] flags=0 service=[sddm-greeter] terminal=[:0] user=[sddm] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>] 
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_unix(sddm:session): session opened for user <user-name> by (uid=0)
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_ck_connector(sddm:session): nox11 mode, ignoring PAM_TTY :0
<date/time> <pc-name> sddm-helper: pam_warn(sddm:session): function= [pam_sm_open_session] flags=0 service=  [sddm] terminal=[:0] user=[<user-name>] ruser=[<unknown>] rhost=[<unknown>] 
<date/time> <pc-name> polkitd[810]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session4 (system bus name :1.38 [/opt/kde/lib64/libexec/polkit-kde-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/kde/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.ISO-8859-1)
```

How can I make my system start normally the first time?

Comment: The Xsession changes seem redundant with pam_ck_connector. Perhaps they're what _breaks_ the login? The `nox11` flag as well.

Comment: So you suggest returning to `eval exec "$session"` and `pam_ck_connector.so` (without `nox11`)?

Comment: Making those changes, then logging out, switching to a text-based tty, then using `init 3`, followed by `init 5`, logging back in and running `ck-list-sessions` gives `active = FALSE` and `is-local = TRUE`. From here, running `ck-launch-session ck-list-sessions` returns two sessions (of course), the second of which (the newly spawned session) is `TRUE/TRUE`. This remains the case on logout/in (whereas previously went from `FALSE/FALSE` to `TRUE/TRUE`. Will reboot properly and test, but expect same results

Comment: Rebooting produces same results (as expected)

Comment: This [gentoo forum page](http://keycorner.org/pub/text/doc/consolekit-howto.html) makes it look like the solution will require the `ck-launch-session` within `Xsession`, although also mentions removing the `nox11` option. Will try that now

Comment: Various changes only make this worse - the original setup seemed to produce the best results (at least on the second login). The first set of changes (as suggested by @grawity) produced something that looked promising, but didn't work out (as documented in 3rd comment)

Comment: I have this problem too and this has been the only place I have found a well-documented description of the problem.  Initially I thought sddm was being started BEFORE all the other services so I moved it from S02sddm to S06sddm in the different rc.X folders in /etc.